# How to return a value in ViewBag along with other values in JsonResult ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have made two dropdownlists. Second dropdownlist depends upon the selection of first dropdownlist selection. For example:

[image]

Now after selecting value from Call Nature, Call Ticket dropdownlist gets filled by ajax calling.

**My query is** I want to display count value of Call Ticket dropdownlist just after the text **Call Ticket**  like  **Call Ticket (10)**  where 10 is the count value of Call Ticket dropdownlist.

My Controller is like :

```
    public JsonResult GetTickets(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            id = "0";
        }

        int CallNatureID = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        var TicketsList = (from a in dataContext.CallTickets
                           join b in dataContext.Calls_HelpDesk
                           on a.CallTicketNumber equals b.TicketNumber
                           where a.CallNatureId == CallNatureID
                           && a.IsOpenFlag == true
                           && a.CallStatusId == 1
                           && a.TicketOwner == 1
                           && b.FollowupReasonId == 9
                      select new { a.CallTicketNumber }).ToList();

        int TicketCount = TicketsList.Count;
        ViewBag.HiddenTicketCount = string.Format("({0})", TicketCount);
        return Json(new SelectList(TicketsList, "CallTicketNumber", "CallTicketNumber"), ViewBag.HiddenTicketCount);
    }
```

ViewBag.HiddenTicketCount holds the value of Call Ticket counts. But I'm unable to return it with the

```
     return Json(new SelectList(TicketsList, "CallTicketNumber", "CallTicketNumber"), ViewBag.HiddenTicketCount);
    }
```

How can I return the ViewBag.HiddenTicketCount/ TicketCount value with Json?

Comment: Simple solution is, store it in a variable and return it.

Comment: In my last line of  return Json ()  how can I pass that variable?

Comment: First just return an collection of anonymous objects just containing the value and text (there is no point sending the additional properties of `SelectListItem` to the view when you do not need it. You cannot use `ViewBag` - just send and additional object - `return Json( new { options = TicketsList, count = TicketsList.Count });`

Comment: can you please provide your ajax call code?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use javascript to get the length of the array you return.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your controller like this

```
int TicketCount = TicketsList.Count;
return Json(new { TicketList = new SelectList(TicketsList, "CallTicketNumber", "CallTicketNumber"), Count = TicketCount });
```

And in Ajax

```
$.ajax({
   //....
   success: function(data) {
      var ticketList = data.TicketList;// bind dropdown using this list
      var count = data.Count;
      // I suppose `lblCallTicket` is your call ticket label id
      $('#lblCallTicket').text('Call Ticket (' + count + ')');

   }
})
```

If you don't want to send from controller then simply do this in ajax

```
   success: function(data) {
      var ticketList = data.TicketList;// bind dropdown using this list
      var count = ticketList.Length;
      // I suppose `lblCallTicket` is your call ticket label id
      $('#lblCallTicket').text('Call Ticket (' + count + ')');

   }
```